# Display ion-progress-bar directly above ion-tabs when slot=bottom

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have an ion-tabs bar like this displaying at the bottom of my screen - `<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">`

I would like to add an ion-progress-bar directly above this, but not sure what the positioning should be in css to achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to hide tabs to show progress bar at bottom. otherwise everything on page will be above tabbars. to achieve this add progress bar into your `tabs/tabs.html` and show it by conditions using `*ngIf`. e.g: `<tabs *ngIf='progress != true'>...<tabs>` and `<ion-progress *ngIf='progress == true'></ion-progress>`

Comment: I want to show the progress bar just above the tabs. Should I just set the position to be the very bottom of the page, and if the tabs are still visible it will display above them?

Comment: If you want to show progressbar above the tabs bar use can use `position:absolute, bottom: 0` to show in at the bottom of the page.